# Sort a vector and store the index of entry of the sorted vector in the original vector

Tags: matlab, sorting

In matlab, I have a vector

```
 A = [2,3,4,1];
```

I want to sort it in ascending order, which becomes

```
 [B,index] = sort(A);
 B = 1,2,3,4 
 index = 4 1 2 3;
```

I have another vector

```
 C = [10,20,30,40]
```

I want to use index to let C becomes

```
 [20 30 40 10]
```

However, if I just do

```
 C(index)
```

It becomes

```
 40,10,20,30
```

This is not what I want. I wonder is there a way of using index and sort to achieve my goal?

Comment: What would the relationship between and `A` and `C`, or how exactly to you to sort `C` based on `A`.

Comment: You may want `C(A)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself:

```
MM = [[1,2,3,4]', index'];
SM = sortrows(MM,2);
D = C(SM(:,1)')
```